# Navbar scaling incorrectly using ul

Tags: html, css, navigation, html-lists, scaling

I'm trying to create this header so that it scales correctly according to browser size.
I've got the scaling of the header, now it's just getting the UL (navbar) to scale accordingly, whilst maintaining it's css properties (i.e hover background color etc)

Heres my HTML :

```
<body>
<div id = "container">
    <div id = "header">
        <img id = "logo" src="SLS LOGO.png" />
            <div id = "navbar">
                <ul id = "tabs">
                    <li><a href = "#"> Home </a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#"> Gallery </a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#"> Calender </a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#"> About</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#"> Members</a></li> 
                </ul>
            </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#container  {
width: 70%;
height: auto;
margin: auto;
}

                /* Start Header */
#header {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
margin: auto;
margin-top: 2%; 
background: white;
height: 201px;

}

#logo   {
float: left;
width: 40%;;
margin-top: 2%; 
height: 80%;
}

#navbar {
float: right;
width: 60%;
height: 100%;
}

#tabs   {
margin: 0; 
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
text-align: center;
height: 100%;
}

#tabs li    {
display: inline;    
}

#tabs li a  {
font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 5%;
width: 10%;
float: left;
color: #999;
font-weight: 400;
line-height: 141px;
height: 141px;

}

#tabs li a:hover    {
color: #333;
background: #F0F0F0;
border-bottom: thin blue solid;
}

            /* End Header */
```

Comment: You are pretty close, what is your code not doing for you?

Comment: I'm working on a dual screen, when my browser is on monitor size, it works perfect. When dragging across to 15", the browser scale to fit window, just seems to make the navbar disproportionate. Also, with larger scales.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use media queries to arrange your elements properly for target devices (i guess that the goal of this question), and example you can try is to put this at the end of your code and the resize your browser to an smaller view to see the results:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 0) and (max-width: 480px){                                              

     #logo, #navbar, #tabs, .tabs li a {                                         

         float:none;                                                                                  
         width:100%;                                                                                  

     }                                                                                                
     #tabs li{                                                                   
         display:block;                                                            

     }                                                                           
     #tabs li a{                                                                 
         width:100%;                                                             
         height:100%;                                                            
         display:block;                                                            

     }                                                                             

 }
```

Basically where are telling the browser to change the property values of the target elements when is resized to a view with 0px to 480px wide. You can use as many media queries as you think is necessary and change the values accordingly to your needs.